# Does the DVD version of Galavant change this joke telling viewers to set their DVR?

Tags: alternate-version, galavant

In the comedy fantasy musical series *[Galavant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galavant)*, the Season 2  episode "Love and Death" has the royal family of Hortensia receiving "save the date" invitations for war. When Isabella's parents ask when the war will be, Isabella looks straight at the camera and says:

> They plan to invade us on Sunday, January 31st, 8:00 PM Eastern. Set your DVR. [wink]

This was pretty funny during the live broadcast, since that was the date and time the final episode would be airing. But I imagine that it would fall flat on the DVD version since you don't set your DVR, you just go to the next episode on the disc.

Does *[Galavant: The Complete Collection](http://www.tvshowsondvd.com/news/Galavant-Complete-Collection/23770)* (the DVD release of the show*) handle this joke differently? Does it use an alternate take or something that has the joke make more sense on disc?

<sub>* This might be the version that Netflix is using as well, but I don't know for sure.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about the dvd but Netflix did not change the joke. I didn’t watch it live but I still understood it. (If anything people will probably just think it’s a joke about the future. Even if they don’t understand that it was the date and time it was aired.)